# Representability of a morphism of stacks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $X,Y$ and $Z$ be stacks over $\operatorname{Sch}/\operatorname{Spec}k$ and suppose that vertical arrow $X \times_Z Y \to X$ of the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X \times_Z Y @>{}>> Y\\
@VVV @VVV\\
X @>{}>> Z
\end{CD}
is a representable morphism of stacks.

Is the morphism $Y \to Z$, then a representable morphism of stacks?